# Tensorflow Eager Execution - Compute gradient between two layers of a sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I am trying to follow along with the guide at http://www.hackevolve.com/where-cnn-is-looking-grad-cam/, using Tensorflow's new eager execution mode. One line in particular has me stumped:

```py
grads = K.gradients(class_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
```

I understand that it is finding the gradients between the last convolutional layer and the output for the particular class. However, I cannot figure out how to accomplish this using `GradientTape`, since (a) both are tensors and not variables, and (b) one is not directly derived from the other (their feature maps already exist, so without a graph they are effectively independent).

Edit: Some more information.
No takers yet on answering, so I'll go ahead and add what I have tried since I posted the question:

The obvious steps are reproducing the first part with Eager execution.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
print(type(model))
# tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential

from dataset import prepare_dataset
_, ds, _, _, _, _ = prepare_dataset() # ds is a tf.data.Dataset
print(type(ds))
# tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter

it = train_ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
img, label = it.get_next()
print(type(img), img.shape)
# <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'> (192, 192, 3)

print(type(label), label.shape)
# <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'> (2,)

img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
print(img.shape)
# (1, 192, 192, 3)

predictions = model.predict(img)
print(predictions)
# array([[0.9711799 , 0.02882008]], dtype=float32)

class_idx = np.argmax(predictions[0])
print(class_idx)
# 0

class_output = model.output[:, class_idx]
print(model.output, class_output)
# Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) Tensor("strided_slice_5:0", dtype=float32)

# I use tf.keras.layers.Activation instead of the activation parameter of conv2d,
# so last_conv_layer actually points to the layer after the last conv layer.
# Is that not correct?
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer('activation_6') 

"""
Now, the fun part: how do I compute the gradient of class_output with respect to
the output of the last convolutional layer?
"""
```

One attempt is using reduce_sum and multiply to get the desired gradient (ignore the `class_output` step):

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape: 
    print(label)
    # tf.Tensor([1. 0.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
    y_c = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(model.output, label))
    print(y_c)
    # Tensor("Sum_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
    last_conv_layer = model.get_layer('activation_6')

grad = tape.gradient(y_c, last_conv_layer.output)
```

However, `grad` is `None` in this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting code from `predictions = model.predict(img)` onwards into the `GradientTape` context manager?

The thing is, if you did not record the gradients going from `last_conv_layer.output` to `model.output`, the backprop chain is effectively broken.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!! Just try the code below.

```
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img)
    if pred_index is None:
       pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
    class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
```